# How does React JSX Spread Attribute work behind the scene?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand how to use JSX Spread Attribute, but I would like to understand how it works.
Eg.

```
<TestComponent { ...{name: 'Tom', height: '1.8m'} } />
```

I assume the first pair of curl braces indicates whatever is enclosed are JS codes. Please correct me if I am wrong. If that is correct, then ...{name: 'Tom', height: '1.8m'} is not valid JS syntax, as can be seen from this:

```
const props = ...{name: 'Tom', height: '1.8m' }  // Syntax error, unexpected token where the 3 periods are

const props = { ...{name: 'Tom', height: '1.8m' } } // This works.
```

Does that mean the first pair of curly braces is actually the syntax for JS object and is passed as the props object? If that is true, then this should work but it doesn't.

```
<TestComponent { name: 'Tom', height: '1.8m' } />   // Error
```

So, how is { ...{name: 'Tom'} } passed on as props behind the scene?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The outer brackets are indeed JSX signaling to deconstruct an undeclared object's properties.

It's odd looking because usually you would deconstruct a declared object, as it reads better:

```
const props =  {name: 'Tom', height: '1.8m'};
<TestComponent { ...props} />
```

As you pointed out:

```
...{name: 'Tom', height: '1.8m' }
```

doesn't work in JS because it needs to be deconstructed within another object:

```js
const example = {propA: "A", propB: "B"};

const {propA,propB} = example;
const copy = {...example}; 

console.log("propA:",propA)
console.log("propB:",propB)
console.log("copy:",copy)
```

But with React, a component's attributes are properties of its props param, which is an object.

For functional components:

```
<TestComponent { ...{name: 'Tom', height: '1.8m'}} />
```

Compiles to something like:

```
function TestComponent(props = {name: 'Tom', height: '1.8m'}) => {
   return  React.createElement('<div>', props, null),
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, what is enclosed within the outermost curly braces should be valid JS expressions. However, ...{name: 'Tom', height: '1.8m'} is not a valid expression (Syntax error). How does that get interpreted? Thanks!

Comment: Because Babel compiles it into the props param of a js function , which is an object (see end of my answer); JSX itself is also an expression: "After compilation, JSX expressions become regular JavaScript function calls and evaluate to JavaScript objects", so what you see is not what gets executed (it has to compile first)

Comment: See this page on React without JSX to get an idea of how things compile: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html